# In Windows Forms C# updating a List<List<T>> updates already input List<T> entries

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have an object called particle that has its own properties (position, velocity, etc.) and in my windows form I create a list of particles. This list of particles is then updated in the code (i.e. each particle's position, velocity, etc. is updated in each iteration step).

What I want to do is add this `List<Particle>` to another list `List<List<Particle>>` each iteration (after clicking a button) so that I now have seperate lists of particles that I can compare.

This is what my code looks like (UpdateEngine is a class that creates a list of particles in its initialise method and then has other methods that update the values of the particles in its list):

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private List<List<Particle>> listPlist;

    private UpdateEngine Engine;

    ...

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listPlist = new List<List<Particle>>();

        Engine = new UpdateEngine();
    }

    ...

    //pressing this button iterates through a specified number of iterations
    private void btPrep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //create the particles and add the first list to the list of lists
        Engine.Initialize();
        listPlist.Add(Engine.ParticleList);

        //iterate through the list of particles in Engine and update their properties
        for(i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
        {
            Engine.Update();
            listPlist.Add(Engine.ParticleList);
        }
    }
}
```

What I see happening is that the first list is added before the iterations fine. The first list added in the for loop is added fine. Every list added thereafter changes all the lists in listPlist to be identicle to the current list.

An example of what I see when I run the code:

After initialization:

- listPlist(0) > Particle(0) > Position = 0,0

After first iteration:

- listPlist(0) > Particle(0) > Position = 0,0
- listPlist(1) > Particle(0) > Position = 1,1

After next iteration:

- listPlist(0) > Particle(0) > Position = 2,2
- listPlist(1) > Particle(0) > Position = 2,2
- listPlist(2) > Particle(0) > Position = 2,2

I'm not really sure how to fix this. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to [so], can you show us the code in the `Engine.Update()` - I feel this is where the problem is.

Comment: Also have you debugged this code? You could put a conditional breakpoint on the Particle.Position = 2,2 so the program halts when this happens so you can see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, the problem is that you are trying to make copies of a reference item, which is why you see all the list items changing.

You will need to make a deep clone of these list/particles so that they arent referencialy dependent.

You might have to add a new Copy Method or Constructor to the particle object to achieve this.

Something like

```
public class Particle
{
    public int SomeField;

    public Particle Copy()
    {
        return new Particle { SomeField = this.SomeField };
    }   

    public Particle(Particle copyFrom)
    {
        this.SomeField = copyFrom.SomeField;
    }
}
```

You can then create a copy of the original list something like

```
List<Particle> copyList = new List<Particle>(originalList.Select(c => c.Copy));
```

Comment: +1 for the guess, if it were a ref dependent issue, why does iteration 1 work? Thats why I thought it must be in the `Engine.Update()`. OP probably doesn't realize how active this site is `yet`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what `Engine.Update` does. If it updates the `ParticleList` and populates it with new `Particle` values, you can just make the following changes inside and outside the loop (copying the list):

```
listPlist.Add(new List<ParticleList>(Engine.ParticleList));
```

However if it `Engine.Update` just updates the inner values of the same `Particle` objects, then you'll need to make a deep-copy by copying the list as well as the `Particle` objects inside as others stated.

Comment: This would only address one of his problems. Sure he would have new lists, but all the lists would still point to the same underlying particles so once his process is done, he will see n lists of the same particles, all having the same state.

Comment: @Tipx true. it's hard to tell without knowing what `Particle` is (ref/val type) or what `Engine.Update` does. The OP might need to make a deep-copy or just copy the list depending on those things.

Answer (score 0):

What you're encountering is because the `List<>` objects are only pointing to the underlying `Particle` objects. If the same particle is in two (or more) different lists and it changes, whether you're accessing the particle from one list, or the other(s), you're pointing to the changed object.
It's like saying that "Bob Smith" is in the phone book, and also lives in a house. Lets say you cut Bob's legs by going to his house, if you then call bob (not accessing him the same way) he will still have both legs missing!

Like @astander said, you could create a method in the `Particle` class to create what is called a deep clone of the object. That method will most likely copy all the properties (and fields) of the original object into a new one. You have to be careful though: If a `Particle` has a field of type `SubParticle` (or any other object), when you do your deep clone, you might want to do a deep clone of that object too otherwise your two `Particle`s (the original and the copy) will both point to the same `SubParticle`.

Also, in your specific context, I would suggest you that after each iteration of your loop, you create a new list of particle copies. If you then remove a particle from the list, it will simply be taken care of by the `GarbageCollector` if it's no longer referenced.

**Edit**: By re-reading your code, I came to the following conclusion: In your Engine.Update() method, you could start by creating a new list of the copies. This would mean that your particles aren't the same object after each and every Engine.Update() call though. To do this, first implement a Particle.Copy() method that returns a deep clone, and start your Engine.Update() by doing something like this:

```
ParticleList = new List<Particle>(ParticleList.Select(p=>p.Copy()));
```